# WPARAM with 5 args

Tags: c++, api

Try to do this:

[image]

Code:

```
WPARAM wParam = MAKEWPARAM(MK_LBUTTON, MK_RBUTTON, MK_SHIFT, MK_CONTROL, MK_MBUTTON);
PostMessage(hWnd, WM_MOUSEMOVE, wParam, MAKELPARAM(0, 0));
```

Get this:

[image]

Anybody know what I do wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: As I wrote in other thread, it is wrong to use `MAKEWPARAM` (which combines upper and lower two bytes into four bytes) instead of bitwise or.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the screenshot. Use the vertical bar `|` to combine the options.